# iptables Bad argument `ACCEPT' in a Bash function

Tags: bash, function, iptables

**I am trying to create a bash function that will whitelist a IP on a remote VPS:**

```
function whitelist-ip () { ssh vps-01 '/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -v -I INPUT 1 -s $1 -j ACCEPT'; }
```

> [jdorfman@mba.local]:~$ whitelist-ip 192.0.43.10
>
> Bad argument 'ACCEPT'
>
> Try iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.'

**It works in the CLI:**

> [jdorfman@mba.local]:~$ ssh vps-01 '/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -v -I INPUT 1 -s 192.0.43.10 -j ACCEPT'
>
> ACCEPT  all opt -- in * out *  192.0.43.10  -> 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hardquoted the command, so `$1` does not expand. Use soft quotes instead:

```
 function whitelist-ip () { ssh vps-01 "/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/iptables -v -I INPUT 1 -s $1 -j ACCEPT"; }
```

Comment: I love you and this site! Thanks so much. =)